# Java map key depending on value

Tags: java, collections

Is it a good practice to have a map key depending on value?
e.g.:

```
class MyClass {
    private String key;
    private Object value;
}
```

And then:

```
Map<String, MyClass> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, MyClass>();
MyClass a = new MyClass("key1", valueObject);
map.put(a.getKey(), a);
```

Is it ok? I am forced to have such a class as value, I thought about using `Set` but I need to get item based on `index` (geting by keySet index) and `key` (where values key == maps key). I also need fixed size with possibility of removing oldest element from this collection.

I think i should ensure that my key and values key field will be always the same. How can i achieve it?

Comment: "Is it a good practice", "I am forced to have such a class" - then why do you ask whether it's good or not? Without any explanation of why you think you need that it is not possible to help you. And in regards to "i should ensure that my key and values key field will be always the same" - I have no idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak it is valid to wonder whether it is a good practice even if it is a forced situation. If you are already in a situation your intention to evaluate it is legitimate.

Comment: @gautham Incorrect, there are other DS that are viable for index based fetch, like a set or even the map implementation in the question.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I am forced to have this class, now I ask if it's good to store key-value as I described because map fits best to my requirements.

Comment: @gautham I used map because of performance reasons.

Comment: "*I also need fixed size with possibility of removing oldest element from this collection.*" But  if you can remove an object then its not fixed size. Do you mean a maximum size? Do you replaced removed elements with `null` or `Object` as placeholders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the keys in the value entities is totally fine, this is how every database creates indices. A good practice would be to have `MyClass` to be immutable and wrap the whole thing in a new collection class hiding details and preventing inserting values to the wrong keys. This is the way to ensure that `key == value.key`

Comment: E.g. i can extend `LinkedHashMap` and override `put` method? Thats what u mean :)?

Comment: Well basically yes but I would prefer composition over inheritance here.

Comment: I don't know if you really need a map as an end result. You could use the Map interface, but people seeing Map expect it to meet some constraints, for example `.put` not removing any elements. So that's why I would create a new class `MyIndexedFifo`, which would not implement `Map`. It would implement `Collection` at most.

Comment: I use `LinkedHashMap` with implemented `removeEldestEntry(...)` method which meets my requirements perfectly. I just didn't know how to deal with my key-object dependence.

Answer (score 0):

Your map store redundant data(double key).
You can put MyClass.key as map's key and MyClass.value as map's value into the map.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) a Map maps a key to its value.
So your attempt is a bit redundant, as long as you don't need the key for further operations inside `MyClass`.